# javascript onmousemove event precision

Tags: javascript, html, mouse, mousemove

I have the following simple html document:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        window.onmousemove = (e) => {
            console.log(e.clientX + ", " + e.clientY);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It should log the location of the mouse as it moves, but IF I MOVE THE MOUSE relatively fast I get very distant points here is an example of the output when moving the mouse from left to right:

```
32, 178
40, 178
52, 178
75, 178
118, 178
175, 178
251, 178
340, 178
434, 178
526, 178
623, 178
720, 178
820, 178
920, 178
1020, 178
1114, 178
1192, 178
1252, 178
1298, 178
```

I need to get more samples of mouse pointer position as I am intending to develop a drawing app where the user can use the mouse to draw a free line
Is it possible or should I forget about javascript?

Answer (score 1):

it's a bit tricky but you can linear interpolate between two given point